# Repeat background with fixed background attachment and rotated container?

Tags: html, css, sass, background-attachment

Is it possible to get seamless pattern repeat with following conditions?

Idea is to have one rotated background with fixed attachment. I think this is how is supposed to be working, but are there any ways of achieving that?

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 10000px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #7cb7b7;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background {
  background-image: url('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/circles-seamless-pattern-10032830.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000%;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

.text {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="text">
   <p>Flex</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty seamless to me, so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @MrLister try it in Chrome. It renders different in FF. He wants the background to cover the entire box. The fact that this is working on the first place is a miracle. Seems pretty hacky to me and only works in Chrome.

Comment: That's right. Forgot to mention it's in Chrome. @Miro, I know it's hacky. Just trying to get some other ideas.

Comment: Would **background-attachment: local;** do what you expect?

Comment: @bummi, no, that just returns background-image to initial state.

Comment: If you can live with a scaling of the image   position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg); should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #7cb7b7;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('images/attractions01.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000%;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;

}

.text {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
   <p>Flex</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the answer? It doesn't work. The CSS now uses different classes and a non-existent image, so there's nothing visible.